# Back up server with multiple types of databases on a nightly basis

Tags: windows, backup, windows-server-2012

I have a web server running Windows Server 2012, with three main things on it:

- Web stuff (html, php, etc files)
- a mySQL database
- a solr database

It occurred to me today that I've been so busy with development over the past year that I have not thought once about backing anything up - and thankfully this occurred to me today and not after the server crashed!

I'm wondering what the best method would be for making a backup each night of these three disparate things.  I imagine I could:

- create some sort of "disk image", which would be nice as I could store the images and easily revert back to yesterday's data if something catastrophic happened, but I've only ever created disk images for personal use, and if my drive is 1TB, the image is 1TB - I don't know if this is the only way to do it though, and I'm not sure I have the hard drive space to do this nightly.  Plus - I only have 1 server, with 2 drives in it, so I'm not sure where I'd even be backing this up to.  If this were the best option though, I'd find a way to make it work.
- I could write a script to copy all of the web files (php, html, etc) each night, and it's relatively easy to write a MySQL backup script, but searching the web for backing up solr doesn't seem as straight forward.  Of course, I think I could figure that out and then just back those three things up individually, but it would probably be harder for someone to get that data back at the company if something happened to me.
- There's (always) a third option I'm not seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many applications that do an amazing job backing up SQL, file, system state or simple file level backups, especially for Windows. I would recommend utilizing cloudberry or some other software package of your choosing to take the human element out of the backup. Backing up the sql database, system state and select files/directories, including the solr index folder.

Also a combination of SQL scripted backup plans and batch scripts executed with task scheduler (like you appeared to mention within your question) would work as well. However if you go that route make sure you are checking it often or using a utility like vbackup that allows you to make yourself some logs! I can provide example scripts I've used as well if you'd like.

EDIT: To answer your question more thoroughly, utilizing applications such as Cloudberry would allow compression, encryption and far lower bandwidth requirements.

Comment: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication

Comment: while looking over this link I found another article on this point that explains the whole idea of backups pretty well: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Making+and+Restoring+Backups

Comment: can anyone create a tag for cloudberry?

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to backup world Brian! I think I was in your position some time ago when thinking of backups as waste of time and, perhaps, money, but you get into the point once being bitten!

I think you need image based backup with VSS integration that guarantees consistency of your data and backups. There are many solutions available with various options, prices etc..

All you need to consider:

1) Storage, basically where you need to keep your backups (e.g. on-site or off-site => in the cloud)
2) RTO, RPO => think about amount of data loss (this actually makes your backup frequency and diary) and recovery speed (e.g. how quick you recover data depends on the case), - both make your overall retention policy.
3) Solution. I've tried different and from the top of my head I can suggest the following: Cloudberry Backup, Veeam Endpoint, Crashplan and some others. 
4) What recovery options you need (basically what you want to protect your-self form, e.g. entire computer, few files, mysql transactions / DBs / instances / option to rollback etc..). This all basically should be considered together with #2 RTO..

Think and weight the above 4 things and make decision. And yes, backups are important, especially when you start losing your data, so you are in rush position! Backups are your insurance.

Answer (score 1):

The disk image will work *if* all the applications are stopped - otherwise you don't know if you have outstanding transactions pending when you do the dump. It's also a slowwww way to restore if you don't need to restore the whole thing.

MySQL dumps are easy, as are the text based files (git with automated git push is a good idea). For solr it looks like there is a backup URL you can call that will dump it but I only use it under Elasticsearch so YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend backing up each item separately. This way, if something goes wrong with only one item, you only need to recover that one item...

It sounds like you are on the right track for the web content backup, but for SQL I'd suggest using the job functionality in MSSQL server (as opposed to task scheduler). This has the added benefit of giving you a history of the job run status.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlagent/2010/10/12/create-a-database-backup-job-using-sql-server-management-studio/